# Proxy SQL Server Request

Tags: .net, sql-server, proxy

Does anybody know how can I proxy SQL Server requests through another application.

I have desktop based application and I do not want the application to directly connect to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

GreenSQL acts as a MySQL Proxy http://www.greensql.net/

Answer (score 0):

Implement some sort of messaging system in your applications. .NET Remoting, WCF, etc.